# Planner "orderHint" attribute does not work

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

If I create a checklist in a planner task programatically via Graph,it doesn't matter what value I use for the "orderHint" attribute, the order in the interface is always wrong/random.

[image: Planner CheckList 'orderHint' Values]

If I try to copy an existing task and reuse the same 'orderHint' attribute values, I get an error message whenever I subsequently try to re-order the object in the planner interface.

[image: error message when re-ordering]

Please help because our TAM says only you can support this.

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tasks/R2FvptrF7EeuH8GmbjyUn5YAAJd4/details

client-request-id: bdc5c383-962b-464e-80af-9bf408149897
request-id: bdc5c383-962b-464e-80af-9bf408149897
etag: W/"JzEtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMi8yMDE3LTAyLTAyVDA5OjE4OjE3LjE5ODAwOTgrMDA6MDAn"
content-type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
cache-control: private
Status Code: 200

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#tasks('R2FvptrF7EeuH8GmbjyUn5YAAJd4')/details/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzEtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMi8yMDE3LTAyLTAyVDA5OjE4OjE3LjE5ODAwOTgrMDA6MDAn\"",
    "description": null,
    "previewType": "checklist",
    "completedBy": null,
    "references": {},
    "checklist": {
        "1386478b-e55c-409f-08f4-24eedf6197fe": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.checklistItem",
            "isChecked": false,
            "title": "Create CMDB Entry",
            "orderHint": "0050812894318267352A",
            "lastModifiedBy": "6c380823-9147-4962-b762-72875c84432d",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-02-02T09:00:34.67Z"
        },
        "1dc8425c-63a9-4463-777f-6db7e8f192f6": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.checklistItem",
            "isChecked": false,
            "title": "Delivery Confirmed",
            "orderHint": "0050812894318311188A",
            "lastModifiedBy": "6c380823-9147-4962-b762-72875c84432d",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-02-02T09:00:34.67Z"
        },
        "cbb8731b-defa-4604-3baf-9830abede10d": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.checklistItem",
            "isChecked": false,
            "title": "IP adresses Provided",
            "orderHint": "0050812894318280165A",
            "lastModifiedBy": "6c380823-9147-4962-b762-72875c84432d",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-02-02T09:00:34.67Z"
        },
        "205f67a7-7083-42dd-40fb-c00de5ecdbf1": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.checklistItem",
            "isChecked": false,
            "title": "Network cabling OK",
            "orderHint": "0050812894318290788A",
            "lastModifiedBy": "6c380823-9147-4962-b762-72875c84432d",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-02-02T09:00:34.67Z"
        },
        "2457a352-bc83-4b55-075f-df8d565416d5": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.checklistItem",
            "isChecked": false,
            "title": "Hardware racked",
            "orderHint": "0050812894318301098A",
            "lastModifiedBy": "6c380823-9147-4962-b762-72875c84432d",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-02-02T09:00:34.67Z"
        }
    },
    "id": "R2FvptrF7EeuH8GmbjyUn5YAAJd4"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the URI you're calling to grab the list and the JSON result you're getting?

Comment: I added the URI and the JSON inside a code snippet in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The orderHint property is used by the Planner app when rendering the list of tasks. The Graph API however does not sort results unless explicitly asked to in the request.

Try adding `orderBy=orderHint` to your query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tasks/R2FvptrF7EeuH8GmbjyUn5YAAJd4/details?orderBy=orderHint`

Comment: I'm trying to affect the sort order in the Planner interface - not a query.

Besides, I'm almost certain I read somewhere that you can only use orderBy with a limited set of attributes (excluding orderHint). Unfortunately, I can no long find such information, but it would not solve my problem anyway.

Comment: Properties that support 'orderBy' generally say so in the documentation. I believe 'displayName' and 'userPrincipalName' are the only two (currently) supported properties. See the 'user' resource type for example...

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties